# Android Google Maps Api v2 loading nearest location

Tags: android, xml, maps

i have created a android app.with reference of this site
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/
 finally application running good.but when i press the button nearest location it is showing nothing.i have created a browser key.but i dont know were to use that.please help.

Comment: Check Out the MainActivity.java file's btnFind.setOnClickListener() method having a String as YOUR_API_KEY. You have to replace with this.

Comment: Use your key in the `AndroidManifest.xml file`

Comment: yes,i kept that API key and also it is not showing any thing.i have genrated a browser key.with out giving any url in side that.is it correct way??

Comment: Boss@ i have used my api key in manifest file also

Comment: were i need to add browser key??

Comment: Did you create an Android API key? You have to add that to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: yes i have created Android API key and im using in meta tag that key

Comment: Did you get any exception? post your log cat..